# What should be correct redirect uri for google+ login

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, redirect

I have tried CNAME, subdomain, http://www.myhatti.com/oauth2callback. every time i am getting error number 400 redirect uri mismatch. My domain name is http://www.myhatti.com

Answer (score 0):

you need to register the URL  http://www.myhatti.com/oauth2callback as a redirect URI for your application in the Google API Console as in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#setredirecturi

Answer (score 0):

You can set redirect_uri to 'postmessage'.